# Linq Optional Where String

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities, ado

SQL IN STOR:

```
select * from Car_Company where (@id is null or ID=@id)
```

What is the code corresponding to the next line ( In Linq )

```
From A IN DB.Company Where (IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text),a.cNAME=TextBox1.Text)).ToList
```

Comment: Try getting your LINQ to compile. It's hard to tell what you are trying to do and what errors/results you are getting that aren't correct from your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend pulling your string evaluation out of the LINQ statement and evaluating it once then using the evaluated value in your query. Also, if the value is supposed to be a number, but you can't guarantee if the user supplied a number, you need to test it first to make sure that you have a number in order to avoid the casting issue. The LINQ query that you supplied doesn't quite make sense because the where clause returns a string not a true/false result. You need to compare the value with something in the data rows. I think you want something like:

```
Dim Id As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Id) Then
   Dim Query = From A IN DB.Company Where A.Id = Id
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally unclear... Try this...

```
(From A IN DB.Company Where IF(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text), 
                               A.cNAME=TextBox1.Text, 
                               "Something else")).ToList
```

Comment: Thank You Mr(ElektroStudios) Error Code :      An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Ok Ok , The New Code ((From A In db.Car_Company Where If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text),
                              A.cName = TextBox1.Text, A.cName = A.cName)).ToList())

Comment: Error With Column Type Integer

Comment: The Where clause is returning a string, not Boolean. You need to compare the result of your If clause with something (in A?).